# Laravel - unable to join table in query

Tags: mysql, laravel

I don't know why in bellow query I don't have data from joining table:

```
DB::table('tags_ref')
        ->join('tags', 'tags_ref.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(tag_id) as repetition, tag_id'))
        ->groupBy('tag_id')
        ->orderBy('repetition', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

I'm getting proper results but I without data from "tags" table.

My result:

```
[{"repetition":6,"tag_id":1},{"repetition":5,"tag_id":14},{"repetition":4,"tag_id":42},{"repetition":4,"tag_id":32},{"repetition":4,"tag_id":103},{"repetition":4,"tag_id":4},{"repetition":3,"tag_id":13},{"repetition":3,"tag_id":83},{"repetition":3,"tag_id":15},{"repetition":3,"tag_id":61},{"repetition":3,"tag_id":105},{"repetition":3,"tag_id":60}]
```

What is missing in results is "tags_name".

My question is how to retrieve data from joining table.

Regards.

Updated query:

```
DB::table('tags_ref')
        ->join('tags', 'tags_ref.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(tag_id) as repetition'), 'tags.*')
        ->groupBy('tag_id')
        ->orderBy('repetition', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Error in query:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'farmazon_lar.tags.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select count(tag_id) as repetition, `tags`.* from `tags_ref` inner join `tags` on `tags_ref`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` group by `tag_id` order by `repetition` desc)
```

Tables structure:
tags_ref: id, post_id, tag_id
tags: id, name

Updated query:

```
DB::table('tags_ref')
        ->join('tags', 'tags_ref.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(tag_id) as repetition'), 'tags.tag_name')
        ->groupBy('tag_id, tag_name')
        ->orderBy('repetition', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags.tag_name' in 'field list' (SQL: select count(tag_id) as repetition, `tags`.`tag_name` from `tags_ref` inner join `tags` on `tags_ref`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` group by `tag_id,tag_name` order by `repetition` desc)
```

Comment: Share your results and expected ? You are using `groupBy` so you will get merged with `groupBy`

Comment: OK, but I wish to have "tags_name" as well.

Comment: Then add another param as `tags.tag_name` inside `select`

Comment: It should inside DB::raw or outside?

Comment: Add column name `tag_name` in groupBy and also change `tags.*` to `tags.tag_name` in select

Comment: Still no success, check my update above please.

Comment: Use `>groupBy('tag_id', 'tag_name')`

Comment: Other error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags.tag_name' in 'field list' (SQL: select count(tag_id) as repetition, `tags`.`tag_name` from `tags_ref` inner join `tags` on `tags_ref`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` group by `tag_id`, `tag_name` order by `repetition` desc)

Answer (score 1):

To get tags column you need add those columns

```
  ->select(DB::raw('count(tag_id) as repetition'), 'tags.tag_name')
```

Comment: Just `tags.name`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this problem. This is a proper query:

```
DB::table('tags_ref')
            ->join('tags', 'tags_ref.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(tag_id) as repetition, tag_id'),DB::raw('tags.name'))
            ->groupBy('tag_id','tags.name')
            ->orderBy('repetition', 'desc')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
```